# Create Slide Per Picture

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have below macro that brings file from saved file from excel to PowerPoint what I need is to update the macro to bring one file per slide instead of bringing all into one slide

```
Sub CreatePagePerComment()
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPPTX As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim pptxNm As String
Dim pptNm As Range
Dim rSht As Worksheet
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim oPicture As Object

Set pptNm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").[PPTX_File]
    Sheets("Sheet1").[PPTX_File].Value = pptNm.Value



CONFIRM_PPTX_APP:
'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next
    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear
    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
        If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
            'Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
            With pptNm.Validation
                .Delete 'delete previous validation
            End With
            MsgBox "No PowerPoint file is open. Please open the PowerPoint file to where you " & _
                        "would like to export this table.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, ThisWorkbook.Name
        Exit Sub
        End If

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If
  On Error GoTo 0

GET_PPTX_FILENAME:
If pptNm.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please select the PowerPoint file name, from the drop down list, to where you want to export the Headcount Review summary table." & _
                Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "This Macro has selected the cell that contains a list of all open PowerPoint files. " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
                "If your file is not listed, please confirm it is open, then select any other cell, then return to this cell for " & _
                "a refreshed file name list.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No PowerPoint File Selected"
    pptNm.Select
    Exit Sub
Else:
    If InStr(1, pptNm.Value, "ppt") > 0 Then
        pptxNm = pptNm.Value
    ElseIf InStr(1, pptNm.Value, "pptx") > 0 Then
        pptxNm = pptNm.Value & ".pptx"
    ElseIf InStr(1, pptNm.Value, "pptm") > 0 Then
        pptxNm = pptNm.Value & ".pptm"
    End If
End If

pptxNm = "NN Commitment Cards.pptm"
Set myPPTX = PowerPointApp.Presentations(pptxNm)

PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate


'Adds second slide
'MsgBox SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex
Dim Nm_shp As Shape, sld_no As Integer
Dim pIndex As Integer, pName As String

    sld_no = myPPTX.Slides.Count
    pName = "Blue Transition"
    pIndex = 3

ADD_NEW_SLIDE:
Dim SlideCnt As Integer
    Set mySlide = myPPTX.Slides.Add(sld_no + 1, 12)
    mySlide.Select
    mySlide.CustomLayout = myPPTX.Designs("N_PPTX_Theme").SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(pIndex)

'mySlide.Shapes.AddOLEObject Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=(7.5 * 72), Height:=(10 * 72),
'   Filename:=[B1].Value & "\" & [A132].Value & ".pdf", displayasicon:=msoFalse, link:=msoTrue

For Each cel In [A3:A4]

If Cells(cel.Row, [A1].Column).Value <> "" Then
Set oPicture = mySlide.Shapes.AddPicture([B1].Value & "\" & cel.Value & ".png", _
    msoFalse, msoTrue, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=(6 * 72), Height:=(7 * 72))
Set oSlide = myPPTX.Slides(1)
With oPicture
  .Width = 7 * 72
  .Height = 8 * 72
  .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 0
  .PictureFormat.CropTop = 0
  .PictureFormat.CropRight = 0
  .PictureFormat.CropBottom = oPicture.Height / 1.85
  .Name = cel.Value
  .Line.Weight = 0.5
  .Line.Visible = msoTrue
  .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
  .Left = 1.5 * 72
  .Top = 1.5 * 72
   With myPPTX.PageSetup
   oPicture.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (oPicture.Width \ 2)
   oPicture.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (oPicture.Height \ 2)
   End With
End With
End If


End Sub
```

What is the required tweak that I need to update in this macro to do so?

Comment: You need to use a counter to increment the slide used in this line: `Set oSlide = myPPTX.Slides(1)`

Comment: thank you for your update. I'm too new to VBA, can you tell me how to add counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the rest of your code is working and focusing only on your specific question. First, there is no reference to `oSlide` in your code, so I assume that's some typo. From my reading of your code, you add a new slide to the current slide and add a picture to it (*or not since that section of code is commented out*). Then, based on the content of `[A3:A4]`, you want to add new slides, each with a new picture. I have discarded commented code and kept your code as unmodified as possible in providing this solution (change the required section fo your code):

```vb
'Adds second slide
'MsgBox SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex
Dim Nm_shp As Shape, sld_no As Integer
Dim pIndex As Integer, pName As String

sld_no = myPPTX.Slides.Count
pName = "Blue Transition"
pIndex = 3

ADD_NEW_SLIDE:
Dim SlideCnt As Integer
SlidCnt = 0

For Each cel In [A3:A4]

    If Cells(cel.Row, [A1].Column).Value <> "" Then
        SlideCnt = SlideCnt + 1
        Set mySlide = myPPTX.Slides.Add(sld_no + SlideCnt, 12)
        mySlide.CustomLayout = myPPTX.Designs("N_PPTX_Theme").SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(pIndex)
        Set oPicture = mySlide.Shapes.AddPicture([B1].Value & "\" & cel.Value & ".png", _
            msoFalse, msoTrue, Left:=10, Top:=10, Width:=(6 * 72), Height:=(7 * 72))
        With oPicture
            .Width = 7 * 72
            .Height = 8 * 72
            .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 0
            .PictureFormat.CropTop = 0
            .PictureFormat.CropRight = 0
            .PictureFormat.CropBottom = oPicture.Height / 1.85
            .Name = cel.Value
            .Line.Weight = 0.5
            .Line.Visible = msoTrue
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Left = 1.5 * 72
            .Top = 1.5 * 72
            With myPPTX.PageSetup
                oPicture.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (oPicture.Width \ 2)
                oPicture.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (oPicture.Height \ 2)
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next cel
```